# Problem while running Spring Boot Scheduler and Apache Camel

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, scheduler

I am trying a demo file transfer program using Spring Boot and Apache Camel file component. I have written a scheduler using Spring Boot that will run every 1 minute which is calling an Apache Camel route and it is doing the file transfer. I have three files in the directory C:\CamelDemo\inputFolder namely input1.txt, input2.txt and input3.txt. My Spring Boot scheduler is as below:

```
package com.example.demo.scheduler;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Scheduler {

    @Autowired private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate=60000)
    public void fixedRateSch() {
          SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
          Date now = new Date();
          String strDate = sdf.format(now);
          System.out.println("Fixed Rate scheduler:: " + strDate);


          producerTemplate.sendBody("direct:transferFile", null);
          System.out.println("Success");

       }

}
```

My Route is as below:

```
package com.example.demo.route;

import org.apache.camel.LoggingLevel;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class FileTransferRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        errorHandler(defaultErrorHandler()
            .maximumRedeliveries(3)
            .redeliverDelay(1000)
            .retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN));

        from("direct:transferFile")
            .log("Route reached")
            .pollEnrich("file:C:\\CamelDemo\\inputFolder?noop=true")
            .to("file:C:\\CamelDemo\\outputFolder?autoCreate=false")
        .end();
    }

}
```

When I run the program, the scheduler is running 3 times transferring the three files one by one. After that the scheduler is not running anymore. Then when I am trying to stop the Spring Boot application by shutting the embedded Tomcal, it is giving the below errors:

```
2019-09-11 15:51:14.711  INFO 10408 --- [n(15)-127.0.0.1] inMXBeanRegistrar$SpringApplicationAdmin : Application shutdown requested.
2019-09-11 15:51:14.714  INFO 10408 --- [n(15)-127.0.0.1] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Apache Camel 2.24.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutting down
2019-09-11 15:51:14.714  INFO 10408 --- [n(15)-127.0.0.1] o.a.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy   : Starting to graceful shutdown 1 routes (timeout 300 seconds)
2019-09-11 15:51:14.717  INFO 10408 --- [ - ShutdownTask] o.a.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy   : Waiting as there are still 1 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 300 seconds. Inflights per route: [route1 = 1]
2019-09-11 15:51:14.718  INFO 10408 --- [ - ShutdownTask] o.a.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy   : There are 1 inflight exchanges:
    InflightExchange: [exchangeId=ID-PCIN467166-1568196927146-0-10, fromRouteId=route1, routeId=route1, nodeId=pollEnrich1, elapsed=0, duration=167106]
```

So  have the below questions:
1. How can I make the scheduler run forever so that it will continuing polling the file location, when a new file comes in the folder it will transfer the file to the output directory.
2. How can I properly shutdown my Spring Boot application hen I want to and why is the error thrown during shutdown?
3. How can I transfer all the three files simultaneously in the first run itself and not one by one?

Comment: Opposed to using a scheduler, you could just use camel directly to recursively listen for new file events e.g.

   from("file:C:\\CamelDemo\\inputFolder?noop=true&recursive=true")

Any new file dropped will be picked up by camel then.

Comment: If we use SFTP and recursively listen to new file events, will we have to close and reopen the SFTP session or one session will be maintained as long as the server is running?

Comment: We will make the from() location dynamic which is not possible, so we are calling the route from Spring Boot and using pollEnrich() where a dynamic URI can be passed using simple language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For question #3 : I think it's not possible, see comments in [your other related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57907062/read-all-files-at-once-in-apache-camel-file-component)

For questions #1 and  #2: the key point to understand this behaviors is that you are using the `pollEnrich` in ***receive*** mode, as you did not set any timeout:  see good explanation about timeout in the [PollEnrich documentation](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/pollEnrich-eip.html), specially:

> **Good practice to use timeout value**
>   === By default Camel will use the receive. Which may block until there is a message available. It is therefore recommended to always provide
>   a timeout value, to make this clear that we may wait for a message,
>   until the timeout is hit. ===

To answer your questions: here is what happens with your current route setup:

1. every 60 seconds the Spring scheduler triggers the `FileTransferRoute` by sending a dummy message with "null" body to the "direct:transferFile" channel,
2. `FileTransferRoute` detect and consumes this message: an Exchange has been created, having the message created at step #1 as input message,
3. `pollEnrich` component in `FileTransferRoute` blocks until a new file is detected in input directory( as no timeout is defined)

   => this will also block the Spring scheduler because your are using synchronous method `producerTemplate.sendBody()` and a `direct:` channel (`direct` component works with synchronous invocation)

   => this answers your first question: the Spring scheduler is actually still running, but it's thread is blocked in the `sendBody()` method invocation, because of `pollEnrich` component polling for new incoming files. A next incoming file in the input directory will resume the polling; the scheduled method should then complete, and a new invocation should be triggered 60 seconds later. There is no reason for the scheduler to stop after the first files have been processed.
4. when you stop the Springboot application, the `pollEnrich` component is still blocked, polling for new incoming file: this means there is still a pending Exchange (created at step 2 above) which has not yet been completed

   => this answer your second question: the "inflight exchange" is actually the latest Exchange created by the latest Scheduler invocation. Camel default [shutdown strategy](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/graceful-shutdown.html) will wait X seconds before shutdown, in case of pending (inflight) exchanges.

I recommend you enable DEBUG level for Camel logger, you will understand better what happens under the hood.

You could get rid of the inflight exchange issue and improve your route simply by using a timeout in the pollEnrich component. Since you are implementing the scheduler logic in a dedicated Spring scheduler, I think you should use `receiveNoWait` mode (0s timeout).

```
    from("direct:transferFile").autoStartup(true)
            .pollEnrich("file:C:\\var\\CamelDemo\\inputFolder?noop=true&delay=2000", 0)

            .choice()
                .when(exchange -> exchange.getIn().getBody() != null)
                    .to("file:C:\\var\\CamelDemo\\outputFolder?autoCreate=false")
                // handle case where no file is found 
                .otherwise()
                    .log(" skip, no file found. ")
            .end();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: long answers on stackoverflow are great, especially helping understand why this is happening, somehow Camel documentation is written for the sake of documentation, not for best practices... it definitely needs a 100% flip.