# Read all files at once in Apache Camel file component

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, apache-camel

I have a Spring Boot scheduler that calls an Apache Camel Route. The Route reads a directory and transfers the files in that directory to another directory. Below is the Scheduler code:

```
@Component
public class Scheduler {

    @Autowired private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

    @Scheduled(cron = "#{@getCronValue}")
    public void scheduleJob() {
        System.out.println("Scheduler executing");
        producerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeaders("direct:transferFile", null, null);
        System.out.println("Scheduler complete");
    }
}
```

Below is the Apache Camel route

```
@Component
public class FileTransferRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Autowired private BeforeProcessor beforeProcessor;

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        errorHandler(defaultErrorHandler()
            .maximumRedeliveries(3)
            .redeliverDelay(1000)
            .retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN));

        from("direct:transferFile")
            .log("Route reached")
            .process(beforeProcessor)
            .log("Input endpoint: ${exchangeProperty.inputEndpoint}")
            .log("Output endpoint: ${exchangeProperty.outputEndpoint}")
            .pollEnrich().simple("${exchangeProperty.inputEndpoint}")
            .recipientList(exchangeProperty("outputEndpoint"))
        .end();
    }
}
```

The Processor only sets the two properties on Exchange. Here one file is transferred in each poll and the next poll transfers the next file. Example if there are three files in the directory, the first poll only transfers the first file, the next poll after 20 secs transfers the second file and so on. I want all the three files to be transferred in one poll and the next poll will transfer if more files are produced in the input directory by some other program. Can anyone please help how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you really need to use a Spring scheduled task to trigger the file polling?  why not simply use the `scheduler` capability of Camel File component?  ( simple route like :  `from("file:/input/dir?delay=10000"). [your route logic].recipientList(exchangeProperty("outputEndpoint"))`

Comment: see similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38103035/apache-camel-pollenrich-is-not-copying-all-the-files .

Comment: I will not be able to do the polling in the file component like from("file:/input/dir?delay=10000") because the input directory will be dynamic. Also the example given in the other post did not work, I think that program is wrong because to() willnot support dynamic endpoints

Comment: Yes I understand your requirement with dynamic input directory. I have provided the above link just to show you that `pollEnrich always works with single file`  (see also discussion  https://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/pollEnrich-all-the-files-in-a-directory-td5750821.html  which states the same) . So I don't think you can get multiple files at each poll with pollEnrich mecanism.

Comment: Yes that is what I guess, Thanks a lot!